# How to know when thread is finished? I want to call a function after a particular thread is finished

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have a function outside this, which I want to call once this thread is finished.

```
Public Sub Replace(ByVal p_objStation As voapPlanningStation, _
                   ByVal p_objGenset As voapPlanningGenset, _
                   ByVal p_arlValues As ArrayList)

    'PUT below in a thread

    Dim i As Int32 = 0

    Dim tasks As Task() = New Task(4) {}

    mobjParty.ReplaceGensetMEL(p_objStation, p_objGenset, p_arlValues)

    'put this in a thread
    Me._replaceMELThread = New System.Threading.Thread(Sub() Me.ReplaceMELThreadSafe(p_objStation, p_objGenset, p_arlValues))
    Me._replaceMELThread.Start()
End Sub
```

Comment: `Thread`s don't compose nicely/easily. Have you rejected using `Task`s instead? `Task`s have a lovely `ContinueWith` that sounds exactly what you're looking for (if you'd asked about `Task`s rather than `Thread`s).

Comment: The best way to make sure that certain things happen in a certain order is to do those things in the same thread. Why not have the thread in question call the function as its final act before it terminates?

Comment: The thread here have a function which is doing some massive calculations. I want to call bunch of functions after the calculation is finished to refresh the screen.

Comment: OK, so why not have the thread do the massive calculations, and then call the bunch of functions?  Is this because "refresh the screen" is something that only a certain GUI thread is allowed to do?  I don't know anything about Visual Basic, but most GUI frameworks provide some means for a non-GUI thread to post a "user defined event" to the GUI or, something like Java's `InvokeLater(...)` functionality.

Comment: ReplaceMELThreadSafe call in thread doing the calculation.

Comment: Sorry, I have tried many ways. but it is decreasing the performance of UI. So I want to complete the calculation & then refresh the screen. Instead of refreshing it on every update. Hope I clear the question. I am not much experienced in threading :(

Answer (score 2):

The `Threading` API based around explicit `Thread` objects is very much *mechanism* focussed. "I need another thread to run some code, so I'll create a Thread and have it run the code". However, there wasn't much thought put into its design at the time to allow later rendezvous - `Join` blocks the current thread until the `Join`ed thread exits, so just blocks you up.

However, wanting to not block the UI is a common desire. So the framework team created [`BackgroundWorker`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netframework-4.7.2). This gives you a abstraction of the problem. Different methods in the worker run either in the UI thread or *some other thread*, and you don't have to care about where that other thread came from or where it'll go after you've used it. You just update your UI in e.g. `ProgressChanged` or `RunWorkerCompleted`.

However, that abstraction didn't go far enough. There's a common desire to be able to want to say "I've got some work to do, I don't care *where* that code runs, all I care about is being able to find out it's complete and get its results". This is the `Task` API. How tasks run, what threads exist behind the scenes are irrelevant implementation details.

And since `async`/`await` were added to the language, that's the most "natural" work of interacting with `Task`s. The key thing about `await` is that it *frees* your current thread (rather than blocking it) if what you're `await`ing for isn't finished yet. You can also use `ContinueWith` if your use case doesn't fit `await`, but most times it will.

For CPU-bound work that shouldn't block the UI, use `Task.Run`.

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple, use the [async/await pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/async/) and `Await` the below function somewhere, the very line after the one containing your new `Await` statement will execute **after** this method has finished doing its work :

```
Async Function Replace(ByVal p_objStation As voapPlanningStation, _
                   ByVal p_objGenset As voapPlanningGenset, _
                   ByVal p_arlValues As ArrayList) As Task

    'concurrently wait for task completion
    Await Task.Run(Sub() mobjParty.ReplaceGensetMEL(p_objStation, p_objGenset, p_arlValues))

    'concurrently wait for task completion
    Await Task.Run(Sub() Me.ReplaceMELThreadSafe(p_objStation, p_objGenset, p_arlValues))
End Sub
```